# Holmgren’s uniqueness theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

I read in a paper the proof of the following inequality:

\begin{equation}\label{machtyginer-argument}
\int_{0}^{1}|w(y,0)|^2 dy  \leq K \int_{0}^{\tau} |w_y(0,t)|^2 dt
\end{equation}

where $w(x,t)$ be the solution of 1D Schrodinger equation $iw_t-w_{xx} = 0$. They stated that the inequality could be achieve by using the compactness uniqueness argument.

"By contradiction, suppose that the inequality is not true for any $K >0$, there exist a sequence solution $\{w_n\}$ such that :
\begin{equation}\label{subsequence-norm}
\|w_n(0)\|_{L_2(0,1)} = 1 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}\label{subsequence-norm-2}
\int_{0}^{\tau} |(w_n)_y(0,t)|^2 dt \rightarrow 0 \quad \text{as} \quad n \rightarrow +\infty
\end{equation}
By above argument, we know that $\{w_n(0)\}$ is bounded in $H_0^1(0,1)$, so $\{w_n\}$ is bounded in
$L_{\infty}(0,\tau;H_0^1(0,1)) \bigcap W^{1,\infty}(0,\tau;H^{-1}(0,1))$. Then we can subtract a subsequence (that we still denote by $w_n$) such that
\begin{equation}
w_n \rightarrow w \quad \text{in} \quad L_{\infty}(0,\tau;H_0^1(0,1)) \quad \text{weak}^*
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(w_n)_t \rightarrow w_t \quad \text{in} \quad L_{\infty}(0,\tau;H^{-1}(0,1)) \quad \text{weak}^*
\end{equation}
The function $w \in L_{\infty}(0,\tau;H_0^1(0,1)) \bigcap W^{1,\infty}(0,\tau;H^{-1}(0,1))$ is clearly a solution of Schrodinger equation. From the compactness of embedding 
\begin{equation}
L_{\infty}(0,\tau;H_0^1(0,1)) \bigcap W^{1,\infty}(0,\tau;H^{-1}(0,1)) \rightarrow C([0,\tau];L_2(0,1))
\end{equation}
and using the above arguments, we deduce $\|w(0)\|_{L_2(0,1)} = 1 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $w_y(0,t) = 0$ on $[0,\tau]$. From Holmgren's Uniqueness Theorem, that implies $w = 0$. This is a contradiction. "

I do not understand how to apply the Holmgren's Uniqueness Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holmgren%27s_uniqueness_theorem) in this case. Anyone can help me ?